# Express request.isAuthenticated

Tags: node.js, express, openid-connect

My Express app calls a request.isAuthenticated() method. However, I don't know what it checks to determine whether it's authenticated. My app needs to authenticate via OIDC. How do I tell the isAuthenticated() method that it passed OIDC authentication?

Currently, I have it set to redirect to the OIDC authorize endpoint with an appropriate client_id, scope. The user's browser follows the redirect, the user successfully logs in. OIDC sends a redirect back to the callback provided by my Express app. The users browser reaches this endpoint successfully.

My consolidated file in one posting below. Because I'm new to Node, it's sloppier than I'd like. Also, because I can't get Visual Code to catch my breakpoints (see my other related post), I can only debug using console.log statements.

If I go to /cost-recovery in the browser, it goes to this route:

```
  app.use('/cost-recovery*', saveUrlInSession, /*ensureAuthenticated*/ isLoggedIn,createProxyMiddleware(sprint_cost_recovery_options));
```

It saves the URL in the session, allowing the callback to go where I want. That works. In both the ensureAuthenticated and isLoggerdIn handlers, the system redirects to the OIDC/OpenId/?? ID login page. I'm able to log in, and it goes back to my callback page. In that callback route, the req.isAuthenticated() *still* says false.

Perhaps because I'm using this passport module, it has no idea that the login happened. There are cookies being set, in a pinch I can just check those in lieu of a working req.isAuthenticated() method, but I'd rather use the tools provided.

```
/**
 * How the application respond to clients requests depending of the endpoint
 */
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-ci-oidc').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
const strategyConfiguration = require('../../config/strategy.json');
console.log('strategyConfiguration=' + JSON.stringify(strategyConfiguration));
const passport = require('passport');
const https = require('https');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {

  console.log('App setting title=' + app.get('title'));
  console.log('App env=' + app.get('env'));

  console.log('App setting query parser=' + app.get('query parser'));
  console.log('App setting string routing=' + app.get('strict routing'));
  console.log('App setting case sensitive routing=' + app.get('case sensitive routing'));


  var http = require('http');

  var url = require('url');

  var currentOriginalUrl;

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
  });

  // openid-client is an implementation of the OpenID Relying Party (RP, Client) server
  // for the runtime of Node.js, support passport

  //OAuth 2.0 protocol
  //middleware Passport-OpenID Connect
  const config = require('../configuration/config').getConfiguration();
  console.log('config=' + JSON.stringify(config));
  console.log('strategyConfiguration=' + JSON.stringify(strategyConfiguration));

  var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-ci-oidc').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
  var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
    discoveryURL: strategyConfiguration.discoveryURL,
    clientID: strategyConfiguration.clientID,
    scope: 'openid',
    response_type: 'code',
    clientSecret: strategyConfiguration.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: strategyConfiguration.callbackURL,
    skipUserProfile: true, /* this was true before */
    CACertPathList: [
      `/certs/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt`,
      `/certs/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt`,
    ]
  },
    function (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;

        const userDetails = profile._json;
        const userProfile = {
          uid: userDetails.uid,
          mail: profile.id,
          cn: decodeURIComponent(userDetails.cn),
          exp: 60 * 60   /*TODO: Get proper number of seconds. userDetails.exp */,
          blueGroups: userDetails.blueGroups,
        };
        done(null, userProfile);

      })
    }
  )

  var proxy_server = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({});

  const originalUrl = new URL(config.host);
  console.log('matched cost-recovery using original url: ' + originalUrl);
  const newUrl = new URL(originalUrl);
  newUrl.port = 8447;
  console.log('matched cost-recovery new url' + newUrl);


  function saveUrlInSession(request, response, next) {
    if (request.params.state) {
      console.log('Saving state=' + request.params.state + " in session");
      request.session.savedUrl = request.request.params.state;
    } else {
      console.log('Saving originalUrl=' + request.originalUrl + " in session");
      request.session.savedUrl = request.originalUrl;
    }
    if (next) {
      return next();
    } else {
      console.log('@@ no next');
    }
  }

  function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('@@ ensureAuthenticated reached. Not authenticated. redirecting to /login');
      res.redirect('/login')
    } else {
      console.log('@@ ensureAuthenticated reached. Authenticated. Continuing to next handler');
      return next();
    }
  }

  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('@@isLoggedIn req.isAuthenticated()=true');
      req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
      res.locals.isAuthenticated = true;
      res.locals.user = req.user;
      next(); //If you are authenticated, run the next
    } else {
      console.log('@@isLoggedIn req.isAuthenticated()=false');
      return res.redirect("/login");
    }
  }

  function getUserProfile(req, res, next) {
    console.log('@@ reached getUserProfile')
    if (typeof req.user == 'undefined') {
      res.status(401);
      next();
    }
    return res.status(200).send(req.user);
  }

  function getUserName(req, res, next) {
    console.log('@@ reached getUserName')
    if (typeof req.user === 'undefined') {
      res.status(401);
      return next();
    }
    return res.status(200).send(req.user.cn);
  }

  var newURL = url.format({
    protocol: config.protocol,
    host: config.host,
    pathname: config.originalUrl
  });

  console.log('newURL=' + newURL);
  var newURL2 = new URL(newURL);
  newURL2.port = "8447";
  newURL2.protocol = "http";
  console.log('newURL2=' + newURL2);
  const sprint_cost_recovery_options = {
    target: newURL2,
    level: 'debug',
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true
  }
  console.log('@@ sprint_cost_recovery_options=' + JSON.stringify(sprint_cost_recovery_options));

  passport.use(Strategy);

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(function (request, response, next) {
    console.log('Common Route: Incoming request originalUrl:' + request.originalUrl);
    console.log('Common Route: Incoming request previous Url:' + request.header('referer'));
    console.log('Common Route: Incoming request url:' + request.url);
    next();
  });


  app.get('/auth/sso/callback/:callback_uri?'
    , function (request, response, next) {
      console.log('CB-1 matched on originalUrl=' + request.originalUrl);
      console.log('@@ CB-2. isAuthenticated=' + request.isAuthenticated());
      console.log('@@ CB-2.5 request.account test=' + request.account);
      console.log('@@ savedUrl in session=' + request.session.savedUrl);
      //var redirectUrl = poppedUrlFromSession(request);
      var redirectUrl = request.session.savedUrl;
      if (!redirectUrl) {
        redirectUrl = "/health-check";
      }
      console.log('@@ CB-3. redirectUrl=' + redirectUrl);
      console.log('@@ CB-4. before passport.authenticate');
      console.log('@@ CB-5. after passport.authenticate');
      console.log('@@ CB-6. isAuthenticated=' + request.isAuthenticated());
      console.log('@@ auth-sso-callback-2 bp1');
      response.redirect(redirectUrl);

    }
  );

  app.use('/login?:state?',
    function (request, response, next) {
      var stateIndicator = (request.params.state) ? " with state " + request.params.state : " with no state/redirect.";
      console.log('@@ Reached login with ' + stateIndicator);
      return next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', { state: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10) }));

  app.use('/rules/username', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, userController.getUserName);

  app.use('/rules/profile', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, userController.getUserProfile);

  app.use('/cost-recovery*', saveUrlInSession, /*ensureAuthenticated*/ isLoggedIn,createProxyMiddleware(sprint_cost_recovery_options));

  app.use('/profile', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, getUserProfile);

  app.use('/username', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, getUserName);

  app.get('/successful-login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('login succeeded');
  });

  app.get('/failure', function (req, res) {
    res.send('login failed');
  });

  app.get('/health-check', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Middleware is running.');
  });

};
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that most of the time `req.isAuthenticated` is simply checking whether or not the value `req.user` is set, but the details can change depending upon your Passport configuration.

As I think may already be clear to you, the `isAuthenticated` method is added to the `req` object by [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/).

For [reasons that don't seem clear to anyone else](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen++isAuthenticated), there doesn't seem to be any public-facing documentation for that method.

But you can find the implementation of `req.isAuthenticated` (also `req.isUnauthenticated`) in the source of passport's [http/request.js](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/http/request.js).

The raw code is currently this:

```
req.isAuthenticated = function() {
  var property = 'user';
  if (this._passport && this._passport.instance) {
    property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
  }
  
  return (this[property]) ? true : false;
};
```

([Lines 77-90](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/1fd591d5cdcf6516d9eb446216843223c0e020c4/lib/http/request.js#L77-L90) in the version request.js I looked at.)

As you can see this base implementation is essentially (1) figuring out what passport's `userProperty` is set to and (2) checking if `req[userProperty]` is "truthy".

(The `userProperty` value is another under-documented or possibly un-documented feature of Passport. You can probably just assume the value is `user` unless you've taken steps to make it something else.)

So effectively `isAuthenticated` should return `true` if `req.user` has been set to a non-null object and `false` if `req.user` is `null` or `false` or `0`, etc.

As you probably know in the general case a passport strategy will set `req.user` to a map of attributes about the authenticated user as part of the `req.login` function (which is indirectly invoked by the `passport.authenticate` middleware). So in general after you invoke `req.login` or `passport.authenticate` you should expect `req.user` to be populated and hence for `req.isAuthenticated` to return true.

Since that's not happening my guess would be that one of these is happening.

1. The `login` function or `authenticate` middleware isn't actually being invoked when you expect it to be.
2. The function is being called but the authentication itself is failing (so `isAuthenticated() === false` is technically correct).
3. The authentication is successful but the profile information is not saved as `req.user`.

Inspecting the request object after a known log-in might make it obvious whether or not the user info is being stored, and if so, where.

Scanning the code you shared it looks like you are also expecting the user profile information to be found in `req.user` for your application, so if that's working at all I would expect `req.isAuthenticated` to work, but I'm not sure I fully grok your overall status.

I'm not familiar with `password-ci-oidc` in particular (and while I see the module on npm it doesn't look like the raw source code is publicly available), but you might want to dig to check whether `req.user` is the `userProperty` it is using and/or whether it's populating a user-object at all.

In particular the `skipUserProfile: true` bit in your strategy configuration jumps out at me. Is it possible that you're actually telling the strategy middleware not to populate `req.user`?

Independent of your original question, the other thing to note is that `req.isAuthenticated()` isn't doing much more than `req.user ? true : false` so if you have a more reliable way to validate that the user is authenticated it maybe sufficient to just use that instead (or to monkey-patch `req.isAuthenticated` to use your logic instead of the default behavior). It doesn't seem like it's doing much more than that anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Rod for your comprehensive reply. The req.user object comes back undefined. For grins, I tried setting the strategy for skipUserProfile to false and it still does not load the user information. I have found that if I don't do anything with the incoming callback URI, it defines the req.user object (and yes, the isAuthenticated). Earlier I was trying to preserve that as a session variable, but now try it with the underdocumented state object.

Comment: Would I be better off removing passport and just making the service calls directly? I've spent days trying to redirect if needed to a login, and hoping to get the data back. It should *not* be this hard.

Comment: If I understand this flow correctly the "verify method" you provide to `OpenIDConnectStrategy` - the one that starts with `function (iss, sub, profile,...)` should be called every time OIDC authenticates a user. Are you getting valid user info in that method? I think the general pattern with passport strategies is that the second param you give to the `done()` method there is what `req.user` is set to. It looks like you're doing that, so is that verify callback getting invoked at all?

Comment: More generally if passport-ci-oidc isn't populating req.user, how are you getting any info about the user? If nothing else you could directly set `req.user` in the verify callback (use the `passReqToCallback` option to have the `req` object added to the parameters passed to the callback function).

Comment: Something else that might be helpful is to pare down to a simpler use case to make sure you've got passport working properly without the added complexity of passport-ci-oidc.

E.g. you could replace your OIDC strategy with basic implementation of http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/. You don't even need to do a lookup of any sort, just call `done(null, {userId: "my mock user"})` in the verify function provided to `LocalStrategy` and get everything working in that scenario then add `passport-ci-oidc` back in once you're comfortable with how the passport scaffolding works.

Comment: Passport is a little fussy to set up. If you don't know your way around it yet it may be easier to get it worked out with a mocked-up version of the actual auth then add the actual authentication once the scaffolding is set up right.

Comment: Looking at your top comment above again, is it working for the first log-in and only fails in the later requests? If that's the case you probably want to look at the serialize/deserializeUser logic described at http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/#sessions 

A brand new req instance is created for each HTTP request, so you either need to re-auth every time or store the req.user info somewhere persistent. Typically the pattern for this is that the user info (or at least the user ID) is stored in a cookie or session and serialize/deserialize is used to marshall it back and forth.